# Avoid Printing Build Successful after ant exits a target

Tags: ant

I have an ant script which calls a target from another script. When this target is fully executed, the second script exits with a "Build Successful" message, which is a bit confusing to the users. I dont want the second ant script to echo "Build Successful" on its exit.
My code is

```
<target name="startRemoteJboss" description="Starts Remote Instance of Jboss">
        <echo message="starting Remote Jboss" />
        <sshexec output="remoteJboss.txt" trust="true" host="${jboss.remote.host}" username="${jboss.remote.username}" password="${jboss.remote.password}" command="ant -f build.xml startJboss" port="${jboss.remote.port}" failonerror="no"/>
    </target>
```

The second build file target looks like

```
<target name="startJboss" description="Starts Jboss">
        <echo message="starting Jboss" />
        <exec executable="${jboss.home}/bin/run.sh" spawn="true">
            <arg line="-b 0.0.0.0 -c default" />
        </exec>
        <sleep seconds="150" />
        <echo message="Jboss is UP" />
    </target>
```

When the startJboss completes it execution, i would like it to not print "Build Successful"

```
[sshexec] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
  [sshexec] Total time: 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) for sharing functionality, means make a macrodef of your startJboss target instead of starting another ant instance with new project scope.
This will also avoid the BUILD SUCCESSFUL output.
**EDIT**

The "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" string comes from ant's `DefaultLogger#getBuildSuccessfulMessage()`.
 You may write your own logger that returns an empty string or any other string instead, see [ant manual listeners and loggers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html) for details.

Comment: Doesnt help here...i will still have to call the a target from the macrofed which actually does things on the other machine. Isnt there any configuration using which i can conrtol what gets printed after exit

Answer (score 0):

Since you're capturing the output to a file (<sshexec output="remoteJboss.txt" ...), then you should be able to strip these lines from it, e.g.:

```
<concat>
    <fileset dir="." includes="remoteJboss.txt" />
    <filterchain>
        <linecontains negate="true">
           <contains value="[sshexec] BUILD SUCCESSFUL"/>
        </linecontains>
        <linecontains negate="true">
           <contains value="[sshexec] Total time:"/>
        </linecontains>
    </filterchain>
</concat>
```

To printout to the user (assuming you're using concat already), or use the destFile attribute to specify a copy of the output file where these lines are stripped out:

```
<concat destfile="remoteJboss_short.txt" >
```

Comment: Those two lines (BUILD SUCCESSFUL and Total Time) will still appear on stdout.